# Create a query that fetches rows plus their adjacent rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select, correlated-subquery

I am having problems with a specific query - respectively creating the query in the first place.
The columns can be reduced to `id`, `seconds` and `status`.

```
=============================
|  id  | seconds |  status  |
-----------------------------
|   0  |     0   |     0    |
|   1  |    12   |     1    |
|   2  |    25   |     0    |
|   3  |    37   |     1    |
|   4  |    42   |     0    |
=============================
```

**What I'd like to have: All entries with `status = 1` PLUS all entries that are less than 10 seconds away from those entries.** Basically, I want to fetch all possible pairs (or triplets, etc.) of rows to check manually (later automatically) whether they need to be paired (there is a column `parent_id` for this purpose, but we don't need that for the query). I could do this in code (first select all `status=1`, then loop), but I wonder whether it is possible to do this purely in the database.

Thus, my desired output would be the following:

```
=============================
|  id  | seconds |  status  |
-----------------------------
|   1  |    12   |     1    | <- status = 1
|   3  |    37   |     1    | <- status = 1
|   4  |    42   |     0    | <- only 5 seconds after status = 1
=============================
```

My current best guess is this:

```
SELECT * FROM entries e0 
WHERE 
  e0.status = 1 OR 
  e0.status = 0 AND
  0 < (SELECT count(*) 
       FROM entries e1 
       WHERE e1.status = 1 AND abs(e1.seconds - e0.seconds) < 10)
```

But this fetches the whole table, and I don't really know why - and it takes a long time to do so (there is an index on the column `seconds`, the table has 9000 entries).

Is there a way to do this (maybe even effiently)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option with `union all` and `exists`:

```
select * from entries where status = 1
union all
select * from entries e where status = 0 and 
  exists (select 1
          from entries e2 
          where e2.status = 1 and
                abs(e.seconds - e2.seconds) < 10
          )
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a18a10/2)

---

Alternatively you could use an `outer join` with `distinct` instead of `exists`:

```
select distinct e.*
from entries e
  left join entries e2 on e2.status = 1 
where e.status = 1 or abs(e.seconds - e2.seconds) < 10
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e16b3/2)

Comment: Thank you! I used the first one, though I changed it a bit: `abs(e.seconds - e2.seconds) < 10` -> `e2.seconds < e.seconds + 10 AND e2.seconds > e.seconds - 10 ` because that is much faster - but that was my mistake in the question. Then I realized you don't even need the union - just remove the first query alltogether and also remove the `status = 0` in the remaining outer query.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do it in a single query.  However there are also ways of doing it with exists or subqueries as well.  Utilizing an outer join means you can grab everything at once with a nicely crafted where and join statements, adding a group by or distinct based on your performance situation will tidy up your results and make them unique rows.

My suggestion on where statements to ensure your intentions are met is to use parenthesis to establish your intended precedence.  It will make your code clearer to your intentions.

WHERE Condition1 = True OR Condition2 = True AND Condition3 = True

Should be

WHERE Condition1 = True OR (Condition2 = True AND Condition3 = True)

Oddly, I would not have thought it would evaluate in the manner you mention because of past experience but then again I ALWAYS use parenthesis to establish my precedence to make it more clear and easier to craft more complex conditions.

Reason you are getting the whole table.  Is because of the data in your table.  Seriously, sometimes we go looking for the answer and make it complicated, I prefer my way of solving the query of yours but given your result set example my query and yours get the same results!  Try changing the 10 seconds down to 1/2/3 etc and see what the effect of your query is.  My assumption would be in your full dataset that your any record with a status of 0 is within 10 seconds of a record that has a status of 1......  I would have commented back but this is one of the first questions I have answered.

Here is some example code based on your dataset and query.

```
DECLARE @Entries AS TABLE (
    Id INT
    ,Seconds INT
    ,[Status] BIT
)

INSERT INTO @Entries (Id, Seconds, [Status])
VALUES (0,0,0 )
,(1,12,1 )
,(2,25,0 )
,(3,37,1 )
,(4,42,0 )

SELECT *
FROM
    @Entries e0
WHERE
    e0.Status = 1
    OR e0.Status = 0
    AND 0 < (SELECT count(*)
          FROM
             @Entries e1
          WHERE e1.Status = 1 AND ABS(e1.Seconds - e0.Seconds) < 10)

SELECT DISTINCT
    e0.*
FROM
    @Entries e0
    LEFT JOIN @Entries e1
    ON e1.[Status] = 1
    AND ABS(e1.seconds - e0.seconds) < 10
WHERE
    e0.[Status] = 1
    OR e1.id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: To be extra sure, I just checked mysql.com - `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`, so `1 OR 2 AND 3` equals `1 OR (2 AND 3)`. A problem with your query is that it will duplicate rows when there is more than one row with `status = 1` in the given range of 10 seconds.

Comment: @Pharaoh wow I edited the post.  But the answer you upvoted is essentially the exact some query as you wrote.  EXISTS should perform faster than the 0 < SELECT COUNT(*).  I recommend looking at your dataset as I suspect your original query was actually returning you the correct results after some testing I did.  See my answer for the comparison of your technique and mine.